# Android studio - plugins not working instead following err is throwing -> JCEF is not supported in running IDE?

Tags: android-studio, ide, embedded-browser

I downloaded [Embedded web browser](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12282-embedded-web-browser) and [GldeaBrowser](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14458-gideabrowser) to do simple things like search google/stackoverflow/reddit/wikipedia from inside the IDE.

But the below error is throwing in android studio

```
JCEF is not supported in running IDE

java.lang.IllegalStateException: JCEF is not supported in this env or failed to initialize
    at com.intellij.ui.jcef.JBCefApp.getInstance(JBCefApp.java:243)
    at com.intellij.ui.jcef.JBCefBrowserBase.lambda$new$3(JBCefBrowserBase.java:151)
    at com.intellij.util.ObjectUtils.notNull(ObjectUtils.java:127)
    at com.intellij.ui.jcef.JBCefBrowserBase.<init>(JBCefBrowserBase.java:151)
    at com.intellij.ui.jcef.JBCefBrowser.<init>(JBCefBrowser.java:181)
    at com.github.gib.gcef.GBCefBrowser.<init>(GBCefBrowser.kt:21)
    at com.github.gib.GivMainPanel.<init>(GivMainPanel.kt:22)
    at com.github.gib.GivToolWindowFactory.setupToolWindowContent(GivToolWindowFactory.kt:19)
    at com.github.gib.GivToolWindowFactory.createToolWindowContent(GivToolWindowFactory.kt:13)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.ToolWindowImpl.createContentIfNeeded$intellij_platform_ide_impl(ToolWindowImpl.kt:542)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.ToolWindowImpl.scheduleContentInitializationIfNeeded$intellij_platform_ide_impl(ToolWindowImpl.kt:521)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.ToolWindowManagerImpl.doShowWindow(ToolWindowManagerImpl.kt:1036)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.ToolWindowManagerImpl.showToolWindowImpl(ToolWindowManagerImpl.kt:982)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.ToolWindowManagerImpl.activateToolWindow(ToolWindowManagerImpl.kt:684)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.ToolWindowManagerImpl.activateToolWindow$default(ToolWindowManagerImpl.kt:662)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.ToolWindowManagerImpl.activated$intellij_platform_ide_impl(ToolWindowManagerImpl.kt:2058)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.StripeButton.lambda$new$0(StripeButton.java:68)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel.setPressed(JToggleButton.java:401)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:270)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:297)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:297)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6654)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3345)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.StripeButton.processMouseEvent(StripeButton.java:329)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6419)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5029)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4861)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2790)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4861)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:778)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:751)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:749)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:748)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:891)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:820)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:757)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$6(IdeEventQueue.java:447)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:818)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$7(IdeEventQueue.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:805)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:498)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

[image]